# Wrong Meta SE link in feed email footer

Tags: bug, email

I've noticed this last time the following issue for feed emails:
[image]

and it's not only for SO emails, but also for SOes:

[image]

Comment: Cross-site dupe on the global Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354622